# Python Selenium: I can't click this exit button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, buttonclick

The exact button I am trying to click is this:

1. https://www.bungol.ca/map/location/toronto/?
2. close the property slider on the left
3. click tool -> open list
4. click on any of the listing and you get to something like this:

[Image for close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9J5Z.png)

Here's what I tried to do:

```
time.sleep(5) #wait for page to fully load
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/button""").click()
```

and

```
time.sleep(5) #wait for page to load
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""html body#body.modal-open div#listingInfoModal.modal.fade.show div.modal-dialog.modal-xl div.modal-content div.modal-body button.close""").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS selector will do it.

```
#listingInfoModal button.close
```

Comment: I tried driver.get_element_by_css_selector("""#listingInfoModal button.close""").click() but still nothing.

Comment: I tried this and it works driver.get_element_by_css_selector("button.close").click()

Comment: When I tried just `button.close`, it didn't work for me. It may depend on the situation. It must have been that the first instance worked for you but may not work consistently. Just something to keep in mind if in the future it stops working.